# Calling another activity from Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Am just a starter ,plz help me with this situation.
What I am trying in this app is 
"I will use the phone camera to take pic (Used One button)" --- I succeed.

After this I have another button which will call another activity where I can see the image details.
Both the activities when tried individually are working fine ,but am unable to merge them to 1 single app.
with this code the app crashes;where am i going wrong ?????

Here is the Main Activity of first screen.
The  class name of the second activity is ExifInfoActivity.java

```
package com.example.camexif;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        Button btnTakePhoto;
        Button Summary;
        ImageView imgTakenPhoto;
        private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1888;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btnTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());
            Summary=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            Summary.setOnClickListener(new screenresult());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

              if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                  Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                  imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
              }
        }

        class btnTakePhotoClicker implements Button.OnClickListener
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        class screenresult implements Button.OnClickListener
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent("package com.example.camexif.ExifInfoActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.camexif"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hasCode="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.camexif.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.example.exifinterfaceexample.ExifInfoActivity"
                  android:label="Exif Info">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is the activitymain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Press The Button To Capture"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Capture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Press To See Summary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here are a few log statements

```
    11-14 16:37:48.516:
     E/AndroidRuntime(22924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-14 16:37:48.516: E/AndroidRuntime(22924): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.example.camexif/com.example.camexif.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    11-14 16:37:48.516: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
    11-14 16:37:48.516: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
    11-14 16:37:48.516: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    11-14 16:37:48.516: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
```

here is the code of ExifInterfaceExample

```
package com.example.camexif;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExifInterfaceExample extends ListActivity {
        private PictureCursorAdapter adapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Cursor pictures = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

        if(null != pictures)
        {
                pictures.moveToFirst();

                adapter = new PictureCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, pictures);

                setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
                super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);

                String filepath = (String) view.getTag();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExifInfoActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("file_path", filepath);

                startActivity(intent);
        }

        private class PictureCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                public PictureCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
                        super(context, layout, c, 
                                        new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE},
                                        new int[] { R.id.displayname, R.id.path, R.id.size });
                }

                @Override
                public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                        TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
                        TextView path = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.path);
                        TextView size = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.size);

                        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                                        cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

                        path.setText(cursor.getString(
                                        cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)));

                        int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE);  

                        size.setText(android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize(ExifInterfaceExample.this, cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));

                        view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
                }

                @Override
                public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

                        bindView(v, context, cursor);

                        return v;
                }
    }
}
```

and the second main xml i had put it main2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

let me add u that I did a clean build and again ran the code this time 
when am pressing the second button to see the summary its getting crashed
here are the logs that are listed in eclipse

```
E/AndroidRuntime(27058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.camexif/com.example.camexif.ExifInfoActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1624)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1423)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3584)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3552)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at com.example.camexif.MainActivity$screenresult.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
  E/AndroidRuntime(27058):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your SeondActivity code and it's layout file...

Comment: Post your full log too.

Comment: **Change** your `ImageView` **id** name and `Button` **id** name both `xml` and `java` then run it.

Comment: @ Tamilan can u please elaborate i dint get your point

Comment: Declare your ExifInterfaceExample class again on Manifest using just the tag <activity>.

Comment: change android:id="@id/android:list" for android:id="@+id/android:list"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a mismatch of Activity name in the second activity.
I had put the first activity name in place of the second one.

Easiest way to do this,is to follow the below tutorial.

[Call another activity from a button](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/quick-tips/start-a-new-activity-in-an-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

```
android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

This line is your problem, somewhere you're casting an ImageView to a Button.

Answer (score 0):

Change the screenresult code with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ExifInfoActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @ Jyoti thanks for replying
but its still not working this is the error 
11-14 17:02:39.324: E/AndroidRuntime(23736): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.camexif/com.example.camexif.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Comment: Post your full log too.

Comment: Remove this code from the manifest file in the activity tag of ExitInfoActivity     <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                </intent-filter>

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button btnTakePhoto;
    Button Summary;
    ImageView imgTakenPhoto;
    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1888;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

        }
    });                
        imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Summary=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Summary.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("package com.example.camexif.ExifInfoActivity");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

          if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
              Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
              imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
          }
    }


}
```

I think the above code should solve your problem. Though I don't know what you are trying to achieve with `Intent intent = new Intent("package com.example.camexif.ExifInfoActivity");`

Comment: Share your entire source code. Ill look at it and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the logcat error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class 
>   {com.example.camexif/**com.example.camexif.ExifInfoActivity**}; have you
>   declared  this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

In your AndroidManifest, you are declaring an activity with the following package:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.exifinterfaceexample.ExifInfoActivity"
          android:label="Exif Info">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

but your **ExifInfoActivity** is in a different package:

```
package com.example.camexif;
```

so when pressing the button, you get an error.

In AndroidManifest, change the package to:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.camexif.ExifInfoActivity"
      android:label="Exif Info">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also, for your summary button listener, your are constructing the Intent the wrong way, please change it to:

```
class screenresult implements Button.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //change
        //Intent intent = new Intent("package com.example.camexif.ExifInfoActivity");
        //to
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExifInfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```